# Count a Model based on another Model with many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Here's my task:

```php
class Task extends Model
{
    public function parts()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Part::class)
            ->withPivot('count');
    }
}
```

Using Eloquent, how I can check how many parts were used for tasks that have end date between X and Y? I want to list all parts at the same time, as there's only several types

By far I got this:

```php
collect(
    ProjectTask::with('parts')
        ->has('parts')
        ->where('end_date', '>=', $now)
        ->where('end_date', '<=', $to)
        ->get()
)
```

but have no idea what to do next

Comment: Please show your model/code and also the effort...

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Done, hopefull it'll help

Comment: Can you add your result and/or expected result?

Comment: is `end_data`  a column of `tasks` or a column from the pivot table between `tasks` and `parts`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assumming the following structure

```
parts
----
id
```

```
tasks
----
id
```

```
project_task
----
id
part_id
task_id
end_date
count
```

---

If that is the case, no relationships are needed.

```php
$count = ProjectTask::query()
    ->whereBetween('end_date', [$now, $to])
    ->sum('count');
```

Or, if you want it grouped:

```
$grouped_count = ProjectTask::query()
    ->select('part_id', DB::raw('SUM(count) as count'))
    // ->with('part')
    ->whereBetween('end_date', [$now, $to])
    ->groupBy('part_id')
    ->get();
```

---

As an aside, doing `collect(Model::...->get())` is redundant. The Query Builder's `get()` method already returns a Collection.